# Creating a loop to display countdown on LCD screen

Tags: c

I'm writing a function which counts down from 3 on a microprocessor and LCD screen.

```
void countdown() {
_delay_ms(1000);
draw_string("3",40,20);
_delay_ms(1000);
clear();
draw_string("2",40,20);
_delay_ms(1000);
clear();
draw_string("1",40,20);
_delay_ms(1000);
clear();
}
```

i tried this but it's clearly inefficient and bad practice.

how could i write this correctly?

Comment: You should consider using hardware timer, so that you don't need to stop the main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for (char c = '3'; c > '0'; c--)
{
    // Convert c to an ascii value and null-terminate
    char str[2] = { c, '\0' };

    // Draw the string
    draw_string(str, 40, 20);
    _delay_ms(1000);
    clear();
}
```

Comment: it should be `i--` in the for loop.

Comment: ...and it should be `i > 0` in the loop condition.

Comment: if you let your loop go from `'3'` till `'0'`, you do not need to add `'0'` in each iteration. `draw_string(c, 40, 40);` should be `draw_string(c, 40, 20);` and you switched the order of the clear and delay.